# Fill Autocomplete From Wikidata api by passing Category

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, wikidata-api

I am stuck on a problem . I am having Code to fill autocomplete with results from wipipedia using wikidata api I have used the following git hub resource .

**My HTML CODE**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Implementing Autocomplete Search using Wikipedia OpenSearch API - Demo by W3lessons</title>
<style>
body {
        background: #a8a8a8 url(bg.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
        color: #7f7f7f;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:13px;
  line-height:18px;
  width:100%;
    }
h1 { color:#F7F7F7; font-size:24px; font-weight:normal; }
#search input {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
  border: 0 none;
  color: #7F7F7F;
  float: left;
  font: 12px 'Helvetica','Lucida Sans Unicode','Lucida Grande',sans-serif;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  width: 300px;
 }
 
 #search button {
  background: url("search.png") no-repeat scroll center center #7eac10;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  text-indent: -99999em;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  width: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
 }
 
 #search button:hover {
  background-color:#000;
 }
 
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <center>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-5104998679826243";
/* mysite_indivi */
google_ad_slot = "0527018651";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
</center>
  <div style="width:50%; margin:0 auto;"> 
   <p style="margin:20px;"><img src="http://w3lessons.info/logo.png" /></p>
   <div style="margin:20px;">
            <h1>Autocomplete Search using Wikipedia Opensearch API</h1>

            <form method="get" id="search">
                <input type="text" class="searchbox" value="Type here.. " onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Type here..'; }" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Type here..') { this.value = ''; }" name="s">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form> 







  



    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".searchbox").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        console.log(request.term);
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                'action': "opensearch",
                'format': "json",
                'search': request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response(data[1]);
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Problem is I want to get data in autocomplete in particular category like if I can use this autocomplete on video in page then it should show results only related to video autocomplete in  or for music it should show fill only music category results in autocomplete or so on from which category it needs to

Comment: I manage to use api and autocomplete is working . But what i want to do is  somehow i can pass category string or something like that api so that i only give results of that category . Currently it just match entered string and give all result without any separation of category 
Like if I search of "ph" it gives php as result as well as physics so i want to categories it somehow so that I can fetch or fill only specific category in autocomplete result

Comment: Is there anyway i can pass searchcategory to wikidata api so that i only get data and fill autocomplete in that category

Answer (score 1):

action:opensearch is for autocomplete. Use the [regular search](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search) with `incategory:<category_name> prefix:<word_prefix>`.